# as3 sandbox violation on same domain

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, sandbox, flash-player-11

As weird as it might seem i am having a sandbox violation on the same domain:

```
    *** Security Sandbox Violation ***
    SecurityDomain 'http://192.168.1.165/52589a87aab101a25e0000de#/' tried to access incompatible context 'http://192.168.1.165/52589a87aab101a25e0000de#/'
```

Does anyone have a clue what this might be? everything works.. but i get this warning 100x times and then the log just won't display any more errors.
It's the first time i ever see this kind of sandbox error, especially with everything working properly.

I'm not the code owner, but i still did a find all for Loader( and i got only 2 loaders who are not responsible for this error.

thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you post your SWF integration code?

Comment: unfortunately i can't, but it's fixed now, i just don't like the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed there was a weird onEnterFrame that was constantly trying to talk to a javascript, i took this away and it fixed the issue.. but i never seen crossdomain errors on this kind of communication before.